# Stochastic volatility: particle filter vs Metropolis-Hastings

Tags: time-series, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, volatility-forecasting, particle-filter

In many of the papers on particle filter I've read (e.g. Douc, Moulines and Olsson, 2007), stochastic volatility is a common example to show that a newly-proposed filter is working. At the same time, I find that many papers in the time series literature (e.g. Cogley and Sargent (2005) and papers that followed) rather make use of e.g. Jacquier, Polson and Rossi (1994) or Kim, Shephard and Chib (1998).

- Can anyone reference a study conducting a comparison of particle filter-based methods vs non-particle filters for stochastic volatility models?
- Is there some other reason why the Jacquier, Polson and Rossi (1994) or Kim, Shephard and Chib (1998) approaches are often favored over particle filters? (I am not claiming they are favored in general, but within e.g. the VAR literature.)

Douc, Molines and Olsson (2007) On the auxiliary particle filter https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3448

Jacquier, Polson and Rossi (1994) Bayesian Analysis of Stochastic Volatility Models http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.11.7111

Kim, Shephard and Chib (1998) Stochastic Volatility: Likelihood Inference and Comparison with ARCH http://finance.martinsewell.com/stylized-facts/volatility/KimShephardChib1998.pdf

Comment: Regarding your first question, a comparison is impossible because they do two different things. Most likely you'll need both--you'll need to estimate the parameters with some MCMC procedure (either of those 1990's papers) and then use those estimated parameters to run particle filters on live data. And when you say VAR are you talking about vector autoregression models or value at risk?

Comment: @Taylor That was imprecisely worded by me. You’re right, but I’m mostly interested in the steps for obtaining draws from the posterior of the volatilities. So section B.1.5 in Cogley and Sargent (2005) does this based on JPR (1994), but I am wondering why not use particle filtering?

Comment: Also, it’s vector autoregressive models I was referring to.

Comment: It’s because they don’t need samples in realtime, and they don’t know the parameters. If you know the parameters, then there are multiple ways to draw volatilities (e.g. pf versus forward backward) so that could be a question for you, but that doesn’t appear to be the case. Or, you might be interested in the different variants of this Gibbs sampling approach by JPR.

Comment: @Taylor Exactly what you write is my question -- if you know the parameters, there are multiple ways to draw volatilities. Why would you choose one over another? Essentially, I will need to do this for something I am working on but I don't know whether I should use a particle filter, or if I should use JPR/KSC and I can't find any guidance as to which is "better" (I don't expect any to be generally dominating the other).

Answer (score 4):

## Background

For concreteness, let's consider an AR(1) with stochastic volatility

$$\begin{align}y_t&=\beta y_{t-1}+e^{\frac{1}{2}v_t}\varepsilon_t, &&\varepsilon_t\sim N(0,\,1)\\
v_t&=\rho v_{t-1}+\eta_t,&&\eta_t\sim N(0,\,\sigma^2)\\v_0&\sim N(\bar{v}_0,\,\tau_0^2).\end{align}$$

Given $\theta=[\beta,\,\rho,\,\sigma^2]$ and some data $y_{1:T}$, you want to draw from $p(v_{0:T}\,|\,\theta,\,y_{1:T})$.

- **JPR**: This algorithm is based on the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. In particular, JPR is a Block-Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with Inverse-Gamma proposals. Conditional on a past draw of the volatilities, you loop through $t$-by-$t$, propose new $e^{v_t}$ values from an Inverse-Gamma, and accept or reject them;
- **KSC**: This algorithm is based on the Kalman Filter. The AR(1)-SV is a Gaussian but non-linear state-space system (nonlinear because of how $v_t$ enters the measurement equation). But if you define $u_t = y_t-\beta y_{t-1}$ (which is observable conditional on $\beta$), you can do some rearranging:
  $$\begin{align} u_t&=e^{\frac{1}{2}v_t}\varepsilon_t\\ u^2_t&=e^{ v_t}\varepsilon^2_t\\\ln u^2_t&=v_t + \ln \varepsilon_t^2.\end{align}$$
  With this, you've made the measurement equation linear in $v_t$ but non-Gaussian. KSC use a Gaussian mixture approximation to the distribution of $\ln\varepsilon^2_t$ to turn the system into a linear, Gaussian one. Then they use the Kalman filter and smoother to draw the states.
- **PF**: A particle filter uses importance sampling to sequentially construct weighted approximations $\{v^{(i)}_{0:t},\,W^{(i)}_t\}_{i=1}^N$ to the sequence of posteriors $p(v_{0:t}\,|\,\theta,\,y_{1:t})$.

## Comparisons

- JPR and KSC are both Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) algorithms. They condition on a past draw of the states to generate the current draw. So to generate multiple draws from $p(v_{0:T}\,|\,\theta,\,y_{1:T})$, you have to do so *serially*, which could be time-consuming;
- By contrast, a PF is constructing an entire sample from $p(v_{0:T}\,|\,\theta,\,y_{1:T})$, and it can be parallelized;
- Since PFs are sequential, they can be used for real-time posterior updating. That is, they can be used to iteratively update your posterior draws as new information arrives;
- JPR has all of the MCMC theory going for it. Asymptotically, it gives draws from the right distribution. But you have to accept some extra Monte Carlo noise. Sometimes you reject proposals;
- KSC is perhaps cleaner to implement (especially if you have Kalman filter/smoother code lying around), but the approximation error is here to stay. The distribution of $\ln\varepsilon^2_t$ is *not* a Gaussian mixture, and the error you introduced by treating it like one won't go away asymptotically. Granted, it's small, especially if you use the 10-component mixture from [Omori et al (2007)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407606001436);
- A PF is technically targeting $p(v_{0:t}\,|\,\theta,\,y_{1:t})$, but for large enough $T$ simple PFs have a hard time approximating the full posterior. They're generally better at the marginals $p(v_t\,|\theta,\,\,y_{1:t})$. To get quality draws from $p(v_{0:T}\,|\,\theta,\,y_{1:T})$, you'd have to use a particle filter with move-steps or a *particle smoother*. For more on this, [Doucet and Johansen (2012)](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~doucet/doucet_johansen_tutorialPF2011.pdf) is a great survey;
- If you want to use a PF to draw the states as part of a Gibbs sampler, you can’t just naively take a vanilla PF off the shelf and use it. The Gibbs sampler won’t have the right invariant distribution. You’ll have to augment the PF with the so-called “conditional SMC update.” See [Andrieu et al (2010)](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~doucet/andrieu_doucet_holenstein_PMCMC.pdf) for more on this.

## What should you do?

It depends of course.

If you're working with simple, linear Gaussian volatility processes like in [Primiceri (2005)](https://academic.oup.com/restud/article-abstract/72/3/821/1556589) or [Cogley & Sargent (2005)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1094202505000049), JPR or KSC are probably the way to go, especially if you're Gibbs sampling. They are tailored for this context, and tuning these algorithms to perform well is less involved than it would be with a particle filter. That said, Primiceri's original use of KSC was wrong. So read the [correction](https://academic.oup.com/restud/article-abstract/82/4/1342/2607353) and don't make the same mistake.

However, if you're considering more complicated SV processes that JPR or KSC simply weren't meant for, then you’ll have to use a particle filter. And if you're Gibbs sampling, you'll have to use a particle Gibbs sampler as in [Andrieu et al (2010)](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~doucet/andrieu_doucet_holenstein_PMCMC.pdf).

If for fixed $\theta$ you want to generate many draws from $p(v_{0:T}\,|\,\theta,\,y_{1:T})$ and sequentially update them in real-time, I would use a particle filter.